# React Typescript: Can't filter an array after refactoring code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, refactoring, react-props

I am building a To Do list project using React and TypeScript. In the process of refactoring my code and breaking up different divs (Active tasks, Done tasks, All tasks) into separate files within my component folder, my project is no longer able to filter out tasks that are "Done" or "Active" (this is determined by the checkbox value that is in my ToDoItem file, it has been condensed to a prop: onUpdateToDo) I am confused and stuck over where to filter out my ToDoItem within my "Done" file as I believe that it should be mapped out within the visibleTodos function. The visibleToDos function is in my App.tsx file.

App.tsx

```
  const initialTodosString = localStorage.getItem("toDoList");
  
  const initialTodos = initialTodosString
  ? JSON.parse(initialTodosString)
  : [myToDo1, myToDo2];


  export function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [toDos, setToDos] = useState<ToDo[]>(initialTodos);
  const [addingToDo, setAddingToDo] = useState(false);
  const [showingDoneTasks, setShowDoneTasks] = useState(false); // show true if not
  const [showingActiveTasks, setShowActiveTasks] = useState(false); // show true if not
  const [showingAllTasks, setShowAllTasks] = useState(false);
  const [filterTodosCompleted, setFilterTodosCompleted] = useState<any | null>(
    null
  );

// VISIBLE TO DOS FUNCTION BELOW //

  const visibleTodos = useMemo(
    () =>
      toDos.filter((toDo) => {
        if (filterTodosCompleted === null) {
          return true;
        }
        return filterTodosCompleted === toDo.checked;
      }),
    [filterTodosCompleted, toDos]
  );

  useEffect(
    function () {
      localStorage.setItem("toDoList", JSON.stringify(toDos));
    },
    [toDos]
  );

// Showing Active Tasks function //

  function showAllTasks(){
    setShowAllTasks(true)
    setShowDoneTasks(false);
    setShowActiveTasks(false);
  }

  if (showingAllTasks) return (
    <AllTasks newTask={newTask}
    showActive={showActive}
    toDos={toDos}
    showDone={showDone}
    visibleTodos={toDos}
    setToDos={setToDos}/>
  )

  function showActive() {
    setShowActiveTasks(true);
    setFilterTodosCompleted(false);
    setShowDoneTasks(false);
  }

  function newTask() {
    setAddingToDo(true);
  }

  if (showingActiveTasks) {
    return (
      <ActiveTasks
        newTask={newTask}
        showActive={showActive}
        toDos={toDos}
        showDone={showDone}
        visibleTodos={toDos}
      />
    );
  }

/// showing Done Tasks function and jsx component with props being passed within

  function showDone() {
    setShowDoneTasks(true);
    setFilterTodosCompleted(true);
    setShowActiveTasks(false);
  }

  if (showingDoneTasks) {
    return (
      <DoneTasks
        newTask={newTask}
        showActive={showActive}
        toDos={toDos}
        showDone={showDone}
        visibleTodos={toDos}
        setToDos={setToDos}
        showAllTasks={showAllTasks}
      />
    );
  }
 if (addingToDo) {
    return (
      <NewTask
        newTask={newTask}
        showActive={showActive}
        toDos={toDos}
        showDone={showDone}
        visibleTodos={toDos}
        handleFormSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      />
    );
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    const data = Object.fromEntries(
      new FormData(event.target as HTMLFormElement)
    );
    const newDueDate = new Date(data.Date as string);
    const timeZoneCorrectedDate = new Date(
      newDueDate.getTime() + newDueDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
    ); //
    debugger;
    setToDos([
      ...toDos,
      {
        title: data.Title as string,
        priority: parseInt(data.Priority as string) as 2 | 1,
        description: data.Description as string,
        checked: false,
        duedate: data.Date ? timeZoneCorrectedDate.getTime() : undefined,
      },
    ]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="greeting-container">
        <div className="greeting">
          <Greeting />
        </div>
        <button className="task-button" onClick={newTask}>
          New Task
        </button>
        <div className="date-container">
          Today is {new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
          <br />
          <div className="current-date">
            {new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
              month: "long",
              day: "2-digit",
            })}
            , {new Date().getFullYear()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="task-container">
        <div className="task-counter">
          {toDos.length} {toDos.length === 1 ? "Task" : "Tasks"}
        </div>
        <div className="status-container">
          <button id="allButton" onClick={showAllTasks}>
            All
          </button>
          <button id="activeButton" onClick={showActive}>
            Active
          </button>
          <button id="doneButton" onClick={showDone}>
            Done
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      {showingDoneTasks ? (
        <DoneTasks
          newTask={newTask}
          showActive={showActive}
          toDos={toDos}
          showDone={showDone}
          visibleTodos={toDos}
          setToDos={setToDos}
          showAllTasks={showAllTasks}/>) : null}



      {visibleTodos.map((toDoItem: ToDo) => (
        <ToDoItem
          onDeleteToDo={function () {
            const updatedToDos = toDos.filter((x) => x !== toDoItem);
            setToDos(updatedToDos);
          }}
 onUpdateTodo={function (updates: any) {
            const updatedToDos = toDos.map((x) =>
              x === toDoItem ? ({ ...x, ...updates } as any) : x
            );
            console.log(updates);
            setToDos(updatedToDos);
          }}
          toDo={toDoItem}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Done.tsx

```
import { ToDo } from "../types/ToDo";
import { Greeting } from "./Greeting";
import { ToDoItem } from "./ToDoItem";

export const DoneTasks = (props:{
  newTask: () => void
  showActive: () => void
  toDos: ToDo[];
  showDone: () => void
  visibleTodos: ToDo[];
  setToDos: (value: React.SetStateAction<ToDo[]>) => void
  showAllTasks: () => void


}) => (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="greeting-container">
      <div className="greeting">
        <Greeting />
      </div>
      <button className="task-button" onClick={props.newTask}>
        New Task
      </button>
      <div className="date-container">
        Today is {new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "long" })}
        <br />
        <div className="current-date">
          {new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
            month: "long",
            day: "2-digit",
          })}
          , {new Date().getFullYear()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="task-container">
      <div id="completed-task-counter">
        {props.toDos.length}{" "}
        {props.toDos.length === 1 ? "Completed Task" : "Completed Tasks"}
      </div>
      <div className="status-container">
      <button id="allButton" onClick={props.showAllTasks}>
            All
          </button>
        <button className="activeButton" onClick={props.showActive}>
          Active
        </button>
        <button className="doneButton" onClick={props.showDone}>
          Done
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />


    {props.visibleTodos.map((toDoItem: ToDo) => (
        <ToDoItem
          onDeleteToDo={function () {
            const updatedToDos = props.toDos.filter((x) => x !== toDoItem);
            props.setToDos(updatedToDos);

          }}
         
          onUpdateTodo={function (updates: any) {
            const updatedToDos = props.toDos.map((x) =>
              x === toDoItem ? ({ ...x, ...updates } as any) : x
            );
            console.log(updates);
            props.setToDos(updatedToDos);
          }}
          
          toDo={toDoItem}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

ToDoItem.tsx

```
export function ToDoItem(props: {
  toDo: ToDo;
  onDeleteToDo: any;
  onUpdateTodo: any;
}) {
  const handleOptionsChange = (event: any) => {
    const selectBox = event.target;
    const newValue = selectBox.value;
    const newPriority = parseInt(newValue);
  
    props.onUpdateTodo({ priority: newPriority })
  };
  const checkBoxCheck = (event: any) => {
    const checkBox = event.currentTarget.checked;
    const newCheckBoxValue = checkBox;

    props.onUpdateTodo({ checked: newCheckBoxValue })
    console.log(newCheckBoxValue)
  };
  const handleDateChange =(event: any) => {
    const newDate = event.target.value;

    props.onUpdateTodo({ duedate: newDate })

    console.log(newDate)
  }

  if (!props.toDo) {
    return <p>Missing To Do</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="to-do-item"
      data-priority={props.toDo.priority}
      id="to-do-item"
    >
      <div className="checkbox-title-container">
        <div className="check-title-div">
          <div>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="checkbox"
              onChange={checkBoxCheck}
              checked={props.toDo.checked}
            />
          </div>

          <h2 className="to-do-title">{props.toDo.title}</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="delete-div">
          <select
            name="Priority"
            className="select-field"
            value={props.toDo.priority}
            onChange={handleOptionsChange}
          >
            <option value="1">Important</option>
            <option value="2">Normal</option>
          </select>
          <button id="delete" onClick={props.onDeleteToDo}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </div>
        <span className="to-do-date-container">
        <input name="Date" type="date" className="to-do-date-input" value={props.toDo.duedate
            ? new Date(props.toDo.duedate).toISOString().split('T')[0]
            : undefined} onChange={handleDateChange}/>
         
        </span>
        <div className="description-box">
          <span className="description">{props.toDo.description}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am unsure if I am passing the wrong props into DoneTasks? Before I refactored my code, my ShowDone() function worked fine, for some reason the conditions within the showDone function are not being called and I am getting a duplicate of my App.tsx file when it should be returning my ToDoItems that are checked.

Comment: This code is a little weirdly formatted, and seems to be missing some parts - the code you shared for `Done.tsx` is either cut off in some way or is a combination of two files... can you try reformatting this code, and including the missing parts?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for reading, I added missing parts, I left them out for better readability of my problem. Still learning how to condense my code to show where I am experiencing the problem.

Comment: The code in `Done.tsx` is still a little unclear to me - do you see how it cuts off in the middle of the JSX and then you write `const visibleTodos = // ...`? I think that's the part of the code where you want to map `props.visibleTodos` and render them, but it seems to be missing...

Comment: Whoops, that was my error, I apologize. I changed it to what I have in my file now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the line below, each toDo item is being filtered through the condition that it is checked or not, then the map function displays each one:

```
  {props.toDos
    .filter((x) => x.checked === true)
    .map((toDoItem: ToDo) => (
```

Rest of code below:

```
          <ToDoItem
            onDeleteToDo={function () {
              const updatedToDos = props.toDos.filter((x) => x !== toDoItem);
              props.setToDos(updatedToDos);
            }}
            onUpdateTodo={function (updates: any) {
              const updatedToDos = props.toDos.map((x) =>
                x === toDoItem ? ({ ...x, ...updates } as any) : x
              );
              props.setToDos(updatedToDos);
            }}
            toDo={toDoItem}
          />
        ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with this line, I believe:

```js
  x === toDoItem ? ({ ...x, ...updates } as any) : x
```

Since `x` and `toDoItem` are both objects, and `===` checks referential equality, this will always be false. They might **look** like the same object, but they refer to different objects in memory, and so **are not equal**. You need some other way to check whether these are the same ToDo item, such as the index within the array or some `id` field, so you can properly tell which ToDo to update.

Comment: You are correct on the location! I have posted my solution below! Thank you.